# Error "user already exists" registering new user using PARSE.com

Tags: swift, logging, parse-platform

I'm new using PARSE, and I want it to manage the log in - register of users for my app. 
The problem is that when I register a new user, it gives me the error that the user is already registered, even if I erase all my users in the PARSE console. And the fun part is that the app still registers the new user.

The error I get is: "Error Domain=Parse Code=202 "Account already exists for this username." UserInfo={code=202, temporary=0, error=Account already exists for this username., NSLocalizedDescription=Account already exists for this username.}"

First I had the register and login in the same ViewController just asking the user if they wanted to log in or register, but trying to solve this, I created a new ViewController, this is the relevant code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class RegistroUsuario: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    var bottomConstraintConstant:CGFloat = 103.0

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollviewBottom: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet var userTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var password1TextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var password2TextField: UITextField!

    //Crear alerta
    func createAlert(title: String, message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)}))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func registerButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if emailTextField.text == "" || userTextField.text == "" || password1TextField.text == "" || password2TextField.text == "" {
            createAlert(title: "Error", message: "Please fill all the info")

        } else {

            if password1TextField.text != password2TextField.text {

                createAlert(title: "Error", message: "Passwords should match")
            } else {

                activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
                activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
                activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
                activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
                view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
                activityIndicator.startAnimating()
                UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents() // UIApplication.shared() is now UIApplication.shared

                let user = PFUser()

                user.username = userTextField.text
                user.email = emailTextField.text
                user.password = password1TextField.text

                let acl = PFACL()

                acl.getPublicWriteAccess = true

                user.acl = acl

                user.signUpInBackground(block: { (success, error) in

                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents() // UIApplication.shared() is now  UIApplication.shared

                    if error != nil {

                        var displayErrorMessage = "Please try again later."

                        let error = error as NSError?

                        if let errorMessage = error?.userInfo["error"] as? String {

                            displayErrorMessage = errorMessage

                        }

                        self.createAlert(title: "Signup Error", message: displayErrorMessage)

                    } else {

                        self.view.endEditing(true)

                        let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbPopUpID") as! PopUpRegistro
                        self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
                        popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
                        self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
                        popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)


                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, if the registration process was correct, it should open a Pop Up view, right now if I try to register a new user when I press the register button I get the alert saying that it already exists, when I press OK, it opens the Pop Up, and in the Parse console I get the new user. So it's "working" but I don't want the user to feel like there was an error registering when there wasn't any.

I'm using the Bitnami Parse Server 2.3.8-0 with AMW.

Any ideas why it is doing it?

Thanks

Comment: Could you update your question with the the exact error message from `signUpInBackground` ? And also include the version of parse-server you are using

Comment: Sorry, I just added the missing info, thanks!

Comment: Consider updating to the last version and trying again (2.3.8 is ~4 months old). If the problem persists, set VERBOSE mode and paste the logs